# Random Walk, Stirling formula, estimate expectation value

Tags: probability, random-walk, stirling-numbers

-)We have a mathematically model of a random walk on the integer number line $ {\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} } $ , which starts at $0$ and at each step moves $+1$ or $−1$ with equal probability of 1/2.
$\Omega:= \{\pm 1\}^N= \{ \omega=(x_1,..,x_N)|x_j \in \{\pm 1\}\}$
, $X_k(\omega):=x_k$..what we do in the kth step
. For $n \le N$: $S_n(\omega):=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k (\omega)$ .. where we are after n steps. All paths have the same probability so it is a laplace modell.

We already show that $ k \rightarrow P(S_n=k)$ have his max in $k=0$ for n even and in $k=+1,-1$ for n odd with $P(S_{2n}=0)=P(S_{2n-1}=\pm1)= \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$

We define $ \tau_a (\omega):= min \{ n >0| S_n(\omega)=a\}, \tau_a=N+1$ for a empty set and already showed $P(\tau_a \le n)= P(S_n \not\in (-a,a])$ for $a \not=0, n \le N $.

***Now we should estimate the expectation value of*** $\tau_a$ for $a>0$:

$E(\tau_a)= \sum_{n=1}^{N+1} n* P(\tau_a=n)= \sum_{n=0}^N P(\tau_a>n)= \sum_{n=0}^N P(S_n \in (-a,a])\ge \sum_{n=1}^N P(S_n \in \{0,1\})=\sum_{n=1}^N \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$

Now i use stirling:

$\binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}= \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2*2^{2n}}= \frac{\sqrt{4 \pi n} (\frac{2n}{e})^{2n} *(O(\frac{1}{2n}) +1)}{(O(1/n)+1)^2* 2\pi n (\frac{n}{e})^{2n}*2^{2n}}$= $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi*n} (1+ O(\frac{1}{n}))}$

So i get above $\sum_{n=1}^N \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi*n} (1+ O(\frac{1}{n}))}=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1+ O(\frac{1}{n}))}{\sqrt{\pi*n}} $

***Question:*** How they came in the script to a constant C so that: $ E(\tau_a)  \ge \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{C}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$

I think of a calculation like: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi*n} (1+ O(\frac{1}{n}))}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi*n} (1+ O(1))} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi*n} (1+ C)}=\frac{(1+C)^{-1}}{\sqrt{\pi*n}}$

Comment: Use rather the fact  that $-\frac12\leqslant O(\frac1n)\leqslant1$ for every $n$ large enough, hence $\frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}(1+O(1/n))}\geqslant\frac1{2\sqrt{\pi n}}$.

Comment: But when i argument with n large i can´t insert it in the sum $\sum_{n=1}^N$, this is also a problem in my calculation...

Comment: True. But consider that $$\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}}=\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\left(1+\frac1{k}\right)^{1/2}=\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\left(1+\frac12\frac1{k}+O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)\right)$$ hence $$\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}}=1+O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)$$
which implies that there exists some positive $C$ such that, for every $n$,
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}}\geqslant C$$
The product ...

Comment: ... on the LHS is $$\frac1{2^{2n}}{2n\choose n}\sqrt{n+1}$$ hence, for every $n\geqslant1$, $$\frac1{2^{2n}}{2n\choose n}\geqslant\frac{C}{\sqrt{n+1}}.$$

Comment: 1)Why is this equation right? $(1-\frac{1}{2k}) (1+\frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{2}}= (1-\frac{1}{2k})*(1+ \frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{k}+O(1/k^2))$

Comment: 2) For the product i only have: $\prod_{k=1}^n (1-\frac{1}{2k}) \sqrt{\frac{k+1}{k}} =(1+O(1))*(1+O(\frac{1}{2^2}))*..*(1+O(\frac{1}{n^2}))=1+O(1*1/(2^2)*1/(3^2)*..*\frac{1}{n^2})$

Comment: Re 1), please check the expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$. Re 2), the formula in your comment makes no sense. The crucial fact is that $\sum\frac1{k^2}$ converges hence, if $x_k=1+O(\frac1{k^2})$ and $x_k>0$ for every $k$  then $\prod\limits_kx_k>0$.